# concatenating text to a column in pig

Tags: date, apache-pig, concatenation

I have a day column and a month column and would like to concatenate the year to it and store it in `CHARARRAY` format with the hyphens.
so I have: `month:CHARARRAY, day:CHARARRAY`

Meaning, for example, if the day column contains '03' and the month column contains '04', I would like to create a date column that contains: '2014-04-03'

This is my code:

`CONCAT('2014-',month,'-',day) as date;`

It doesn't work and I'm not quite sure how to concatenate additional text onto the column.
I would like to note that I'm not sure converting to date format is an option for me. I would prefer to keep it in `CHARARRAY` format since I would like to join with another file that has date stored in `CHARARRAY` format.

Comment: I think I may have solved it:
concat(concat(concat('2014-',month),'-'),day) as date;

Comment: Just a remark: Concat in the next Pig version (0.13.0) will support varargs so you'll able to do what you initially tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is the data file called dateExample.csv:

```
     Surender,02,03,1988
     Raja,12,09,1998
     Raj,05,10,1986
```

This is the script for pig:

```
   A = LOAD 'dateExample.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:chararray,day:chararray,month:long,year:chararray);
   X = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT((chararray)day,CONCAT('-',CONCAT((chararray)month,CONCAT('-',(chararray)year))));
   dump X;
```

You will get the desired output:

```
   (02-3-1988)
   (12-9-1998)
   (05-10-1986)
```

### Explanation:

When we try to concat like this:

```
   X = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(day,CONCAT('-',CONCAT(month,CONCAT('-',year))));
```

We get following exception :

```
  ERROR 1045: 
  <line 2, column 45> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.CONCAT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

So we need to explicitly cast the day,month and year values to chararray and it works!!